# Is it "mechayei meisim UHTTuh" or "mechayeh meisim atTUH" (rav lehoshia) in shmoneh esrei?

Tags: pronunciation, grammar-dikduk, chazzan-prayer-leader, prayer-book, tefilla

I've seen both pronunciations (at the beginning of the second bracha in shmoneh esrei):

- Aleph-patach, tav-kuhmuhtz, heh (implied stress on second syllable)
- Aleph-kuhmuhtz-meseg, tav-kuhmuhtz, heh (noted stress on first syllable)

Comment: Maybe it has to do with whether the next phrase "rav l'hoshi'a" is a continuation of this one or not. For what it's worth, a bunch of the ראשונים, including אבודרהם, have them as apparently separate phrases. But I'm just guessing.

Comment: I've seen a third: Aleph-patach, tav-kuhmuhtz, heh (stress marked on the first syllable ... to prevent one from making the mistake in your first option?)

Comment: @Yahu - That's how it's pronounced in the song (which is now stuck in my head).

Answer (score 5):

It should be מלעיל, because of the rule of נסוג אחור

Since the next word (רב) has its stress on the first syllable, the stress of the preceding word moves up to avoid having two stresses in a row.

However, if רב להושיע is a separate phrase, this rule might not apply.

Answer (score 2):

I don't if it's an official rule but I remarked (in Sepahradi Siddur like Ich Matsliah') that when Ata is after the attribute, the word is mileel (stress on the second to last syllable) but when the word is before the attribute, it's milera (stress on the last syllable)

Ex: At**a** guibor
Ex: Melekh Rah'oum Veh'anoun **A**ta.